# how to check the index of 2 arrays are same or no?

Tags: python, arrays, passwords

if I have 2 arrays, 1 for username and 1 for password. How can I check username[0] is == to password[0] and so on for all the numbers in the array? So far the code looks like this:

```
username_aray = ["tina", "john", "kath", "lina", "luke", "ali"]
password_aray = ["tr.35", "sj.34", "kj.45", "kfj.67", "xdjbh.20", "djmv.92"]


   

     username = input("Please enter in your username: ")
        if username in username_aray:
            print("username found! ")
        else:
            print ("Invalid Username!! ")
    
    
    
        password = input("Please enter in your password: ")
        if password in password_aray:
            if both ==[]:
                print(correct password")
            else:
                print ("Invalid Password!! ")
        else:
            print("Invalid Password! ")
```

With the following code it doesn't recognize body as I haven't defined it and I don't know how to check if username entered matches the password (keeping in mind that username index 0 and password index 0 match each other).

Comment: use a dictionary (`dic = dict(zip(username_aray,password_aray))`), not lists, this will make your life easier ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should use a dictionnary but if the use of list is mandatory you could do something like that :

```py
username = input("Please enter in your username: ")
if username in username_aray:
    print("username found! ")
else:
    print ("Invalid Username!! ")



password = input("Please enter in your password: ")
if password == password_aray[username_aray.index(username)]:
    print("correct password")
else:
    print("Invalid Password! ")
```

`your_list.index(elem)` return the index of elem in the list (if present). Which allow you to test if the element at the same index in another list is the same.